# Value of $C$ changing in a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} + 5y = 20$ with $y(0)=2$.

This is my attempt:

$$\ln|20-5y|=-5x+C$$
$$20-5y=Ce^{-5x}$$
$$y=\frac{Ce^{-5x}}{-5}+4$$
Then plugging the initial condition gives $C=10$.

Here, the value of $C$ changes on different steps.

You could look at the first line and say $C$ is $\ln 10$, you could look at the last line and say $C$ is $10$, or you could consider $C / (-5)$ as $C$ and say it is $-2$.

What is the correct answer of $C$? Why does it change like this?

Comment: So assign different variable names. Don't let $C=e^C$ or $C=\frac{C}{-5}$.

Comment: If the question had `y(0) = 2` what would C be? I thought C could be any real number. I think I need to do some reading on the fundamental concept of C, since I'm not too sure how it works other than it is something that is added after integration

Comment: My friend told me the answer to C is -2, but in the answer key my teacher made C is ln 10

Comment: If the friend lets $y = Ce^{-5x} + 4$ while the teacher lets $y = \dfrac{Ce^{-5x}-20}{-5}$, then they can get different $C$s that means different things.

Comment: Next time please use an app like MathPix to convert your handwriting to LaTeX. Or learn how to use LaTeX.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to draw it on a mouse. Will try that out, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'C' in the first line, let's call it C1 is $ln10$ as you've mentioned.
The 'C' in the second line in your post (call it C2) is not the same as C1, it is in fact $e^{C1}$, and $e^{ln10}$ is 10 by the properties of natural logarithms.
The goal of solving diff equations most of the time is to remove the diff (dy/dx) and find the equation. You can do so in the first line itself by using y(0) = 2, the original equation would become the following:

$ln(20 - 5y) = -5x + ln(10)$ ..........(1)

Or you can go to the second line and using y(0) = 2, you would get C = 10 (what we have defined above as C2) and then the original equation would become:

$20 - 5y = 10e^{-5x} $..............(2)

Both equations 1 and 2 represent the same pair of values or the same curve given that their domains are the same (due to the restrictions of log function as in equation 1, y can be at most 4).

Comment: Please 
[format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: My bad, didn't know how to use LateX here, will use it from now on. Thanks for editing this one!